# Buenas tengo un error en la forma de pasar las dos variables DNI='$DNI' y numero='.$row['ReferenciaLibro'].'

Tags: php

Ayudarme porfavor tengo un error en DNI='$DNI' & numero='.$row['ReferenciaLibro'].'
Me gustaria saber como podria cambiar la sentencia para poder pasar las dos variables sin tener error

el codigo:

```
echo "<table align='center' border='1'>
<tr>
<th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> ReferenciaLibro  </th>
<th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> TituloLibro      </th>
<th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> FechaReserva     </th>
<th class ='bg-info' scope = 'col'> Opcion           </th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$row[$ReferenciaLibro]."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row[$TituloLibro]."</td>"; 
echo "<td>".$row[$FechaReserva]."</td>"; 
echo '<td >';
echo "<div class='ui mini buttons'>";
echo '<a class="ui mini positive button" href=cancelarreservalibrosadminusuario.php?DNI='$DNI' & numero='.$row['ReferenciaLibro'].'> Cancelar</a>';  
echo "</div>"; 
echo '</td>';       
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: podrías pegar el error qué te da?

Comment: me dice que $DNI unexpected

Comment: te faltan los 2 puntos para concatenar variables: '.$DNI.'

Answer (score 0):

Esta línea no concatena correctamente una variable con un string. Hacen faltan los puntos que concatenan una variable con un string:

```
echo '<a class="ui mini positive button" href=cancelarreservalibrosadminusuario.php?DNI='$DNI' & numero='.$row['ReferenciaLibro'].'> Cancelar</a>';
```

De este modo debería funcionar:

```
$url = "cancelarreservalibrosadminusuario.php?DNI=".$DNI."&numero=".$row['ReferenciaLibro'];
echo "<a class='ui mini positive button' href='".$url."'> Cancelar</a>";
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono

Comment: y para pasar el numero dni

Comment: aqui en este codigo:
echo '<script language="javascript">alert("se cancelo tu reserva");'
        . 'window.location.href="usuarioadmin.php";'
                . '</script>';